# Bootstrap Alert Messages in PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, alert, message, using

I'm a little bit confused about alert messages in bootstrap and using them in my PHP code. I have an if/else statement and I want the alert success of bootstrap in my if statement block and also danger alert in an else statement block, kindly check my code.

```
if($mysqli->query($sql) == = true){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You!now please login </div>';
    header("location:login.php");

} else {

    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Registration Failed, Something Wrong With Your Details")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: you can't send header after you started to send output with `echo` in your `true` statement.

Comment: in block of code "IF" i want to alert bootstrap success message and then user should be redirect to login page thats it sir :) PeterFeatherstone Featherstone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it like

```
<?php
if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
  echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You!now please login </div>';
  header("Refresh: 3; URL=http://yoursite.com/login.php");
}?>
```

It will redirect user to login page after 3 seconds as `Refresh: 3` is set.

Click [header: php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114)

Comment: Thank You Very Much Bro :)
It Works

Comment: its ok man really appreciate your time and help , @Nana Partykar

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
header( "refresh:5;url=login.php" );
```

In you IF statement.

Where 5 is time in sec to delay

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
    $errorStatus = "success";
    $errorMessage="Thank You!now please login";
    header("location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode($errorMessage)."&".urlencode($errorStatus));
}else {
    $errorStatus = "danger";
    $errorMessage="Registration Failed, Something Wrong With Your Details";
    header("location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode($errorMessage)."&".urlencode($errorStatus));
}
```

And in login.php

```
$errorStatus = $_GET['errorStatus'];
$errorMessage = $_GET['errorMessage'];
$result='<div class="alert alert-<?php echo $errorStatus ?>"><?php echo $errorMessage ?></div>';
```

I am just showing you a way other conditions you have to write for checking the variables.

Comment: no you didn't get me , kindly read it carefully.

In block of code "IF" i want to alert bootstrap success message and then user should be redirect to login page thats it sir :)